# WP plugin Polylang "copy" articles to all languages by default

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way how to set up `Polylang` (or some other translation plugin for WordPress) so that when I write an article or a page in one language (the default one) it will just make an exact copy of it and set it for the other languages. So the article/page is at least visible until I get my translator guy to translate it. Also he doesn't have to copy or write the article again and he just translates which is much more convenient.

Also, I'm struggling a bit with the translation of media. I know that I can turn it off, but I it would be awesome if I could use the same image and just add different translations to it, instead of uploading the same image for each language and just changing the description.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Late for the party, I know, but I faced a similar problem and wrote a little plugin: https://bitbucket.org/skurrilewelt/polylang-copy